# Create new product by calliing shopify api

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, https, shopify-app

I am trying to create a new product by calling the shopify product api (/admin/api/2020-01/products.json). I am trying to achieve this using the "https" module. Below is the sample code

```
const url1 = 'https://{api_token}@tuscstore.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-01/products.json';
    var obj = {
      "product":[
          {
              "title": "Saturn",
              "body_html": "<p>The epitome of elegance</p>",
              "vendor": "Soltions inc",
              "product_type": "Planets",
              "handle": "saturn",
              "tags": "",
              "images": [
                  {
                      "src": "https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/system/stellar_items/image_files/38_saturn_1600x900.jpg"
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
    };

const https = require('https');

var data = JSON.stringify(obj)

const options = new URL(url1);

var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

/*   res.on('data', (d) => {
     process.stdout.write(d);
  }); */
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});

req.write(data);
req.end();

const Index = () => (
    <div>
      <p>Sample app using React and Next.js</p>
    </div>
  );

export default Index;
```

I am facing 2 problems,

1. when I do "process.stdout.write(d)", I receive cannot readproperty "write" undefined.
2. If I comment it out as I have done in
   the code above, I don't get the error.

In either case I get the statuscode as 200, and not 201 which is what I shoudl receive according to shopify's docs.

Can someone please help me with what is going wrong?

Edit: Using Post,I get a type error

```
const https = require('https');

var data = JSON.stringify(obj)


var options = {
  hostname: 'https://{apikey:password}@tuscstore.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-01',
  path: '/products.json',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       /*'Content-Length': data.length*/
       'Authorization' : 'API_TOKEN'
     }
};


var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});

req.write(data);
req.end();
```

TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Failed to parse URL from https://[https://{APIKEY:PWD}@tuscstore.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-01]/products.json

Answer (score 1):

you creating a new product you have to make http POST request , and now your making http GET request you should update your `options` like so :

```
const options = {
  hostname: 'https://apikey:password@<@store_url>/admin/api/2020-01', // your host name
  path: '/shop.json', // your end point
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization' : 'YOUR_API_TOKEN'
  }
}
```

OR you can use this package to solve all your problems https://www.npmjs.com/package/shopify-api-node

Comment: 'Authorization' : 'YOUR_API_TOKEN', is this the token from my partner account?

Comment: base on the document it seems to be your token from your partner account